# Does Necromancer make sense if I answered a new question, then it was merged with an old question?

Tags: bug, status-deferred

I answered a new question and also flagged it as a duplicate of an existing question. A moderator expertly merged it with the [existing, somewhat old question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/how-to-lose-fat-only-in-your-thigh). I subsequently received the Necromancer badge.

Is this by design? If it's unintended, does it make sense? (I realize the stakes--badges--are low.)

Comment: Logically, it makes sense. What's the reason why you think it's not merited?

Comment: I can see it both ways. On the one hand, all I did was answer a new question that happened to get merged with an old one. On the other hand, because I did so, the old question got answered. In **this** case, I was the reason for it getting merged--but if I weren't, it would be a little weird. Doesn't much matter--since Jeff is indicating that changing it in the back-end would be ugly, I don't think it's worth worrying about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue with necromancer. There's no real way to fix it w/r/t merged questions that isn't unspeakably painful, so.. enjoy your badge. :)